# Find html element nearest to position (relative or absolute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given absolute or relative position (top & left) is there any way to get the nearest html element to these co-ordinates?

Or alternately, is there any way to craft a selector (or use some jQuery construct) to enumerate elements and then find which is closes to the provided co-ordinates? Assume that the set of elements is small and finite.

Comment: I also make the assumption you determine "closest" as the closest top/left?  What about an element within an element?  If it is contained, is it "closest" to its parent?

Comment: this is a predefined set of elements, and a flat list so thankfully it's not as complex as some other cases. Closest is in terms of top/left offset.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've built a jQuery method that returns closest element to offset, within the collection:

```
jQuery.fn.closestToOffset = function(offset) {
    var el = null,
        elOffset,
        x = offset.left,
        y = offset.top,
        distance,
        dx,
        dy,
        minDistance;
    this.each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        elOffset = $t.offset();
        right = elOffset.left + $t.width();
        bottom = elOffset.top + $t.height();

        if (
            x >= elOffset.left &&
            x <= right &&
            y >= elOffset.top &&
            y <= bottom
        ) {
            el = $t;
            return false;
        }

        var offsets = [
            [elOffset.left, elOffset.top],
            [right, elOffset.top],
            [elOffset.left, bottom],
            [right, bottom],
        ];
        for (var off in offsets) {
            dx = offsets[off][0] - x;
            dy = offsets[off][1] - y;
            distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (minDistance === undefined || distance < minDistance) {
                minDistance = distance;
                el = $t;
            }
        }
    });
    return el;
};
```

Notes:

1. If the offset is **inside** one of the elements, it will be returned.
2. I'm looping through four offsets, because this gives the best accuracy.

Use it like this:

```
$('div.myCollection').closestToOffset({left: 5, top: 5});
```

Comment: I am curious what the performance's like if you have a lot of elements (like thousands).

Comment: I'm using this function and it works well, even with many elements. It should be O(n). And anyway I don't think that you can reduce the total time, so just try and see if it works for you.

Comment: If div.myCollection contains nested elements, you may want to keep looking until you find the innermost element that the point is inside.  Document.elementFromPoint() might also be a good place to start.

Comment: Can you update this answer?
Copy/paste function is giving a parentheses error.

Comment: Can you post the error please? the function is still working for me.

Comment: `offset()` returns (only) `top` & `left` http://api.jquery.com/offset/, so an updated version would probably need to calculate the bottom & right using `height()` & `width()`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the bugs to the previous answer (also cleaned up to ES6):

```
const getClosestElement = (x, y) => {
  const elements = $('body *');
  let closestEl = elements.eq(0); //initialize to first element
  let offset = closestEl.offset();
  offset.left += closestEl.outerWidth() / 2; // center of object
  offset.top += closestEl.outerHeight() / 2; // middle of object
  let minDist = Math.sqrt((offset.left - x) * (offset.left - x) + (offset.top - y) * (offset.top - y));

  elements.each((i) => {
    const el = elements.eq(i);
    offset = el.offset();
    offset.left += el.outerWidth() / 2; // center of object
    offset.top += el.outerHeight() / 2; // middle of object
    const dist = Math.sqrt((offset.left - x) * (offset.left - x) + (offset.top - y) * (offset.top - y));
    if (dist < minDist) {
      minDist = dist;
      closestEl = el;
    }
  });

  return closestEl;
};
```

Comment: Why this bug-ridden answer has been allowed to sit here for five years ready to annoy the next sucker to come along, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of to do this would be to have a search function loop that loops through all your existing elements and compares the co-ordinates, keeping a copy of the nearest variable all the time.

Thats the way I can think of doing this, and what I would do if I was under your constraints.

Comment: thanks... that's what I think/know will work, but would definitely prefer another solution is possible.

Comment: @psychotik: Just make sure to not measure the dimensions of elements in the loop. Every measure triggers a browser reflow. Just `top` and `left` is fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Felix answer and applied it to vanilla Js for my requirements, I know it's an old question but if anyone needs it

```
function getClosestChoice(x, y, elements) {
  let closestEl,
    minDist,
    offset;

  elements.forEach((el) => {
    offset = { left: el.offsetLeft, top: el.offsetTop };
    offset.left += el.offsetWidth / 2;
    offset.top += el.offsetHeight / 2;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(
      (offset.left - x) * (offset.left - x) + (offset.top - y) * (offset.top - y)
    );
    if (!minDist || dist < minDist) {
      minDist = dist;
      closestEl = el;
    }
  });
  return closestEl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptation of accepted answer without jquery in typescript

```
export interface XYCoord {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
export function getNearestElement(els: Element[], { x, y }: XYCoord): Element {
  let el: Element, elOffset, distance, dx, dy, minDistance: number | undefined
  els.some((cel) => {
    elOffset = cel.getBoundingClientRect()
    const right = elOffset.left + elOffset.width
    const bottom = elOffset.top + elOffset.height

    if (x >= elOffset.left && x <= right && y >= elOffset.top && y <= bottom) {
      el = cel
      return true
    }

    const offsets = [
      [elOffset.left, elOffset.top],
      [right, elOffset.top],
      [elOffset.left, bottom],
      [right, bottom],
    ]
    offsets.forEach((_, i) => {
      dx = offsets[i][0] - x
      dy = offsets[i][1] - y
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
      if (minDistance === undefined || distance < minDistance) {
        minDistance = distance
        el = cel
      }
    })
    return false
  })!

  return el!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or try the original jQuery function [offsetparent()](http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/). From this page comes the next example:

```
$( "li.item-a" ).offsetParent().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: Closest to position, not in DOM