# Get item below another item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

If you have a document full of absolute positioned items and you set a document click handler (*document.onclick = handler*). Is it possible to get all objects that share the mouse position? i.e. two div boxes overlapped, not only the top one

Comment: I *think* this has been asked once before, but the other question is extremely hard to find. Maybe worth digging if nothing comes up. (**Edit**: I think this was what I had in mind, but it doesn't do what is asked here: [2337630](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337630/find-html-element-nearest-to-position-relative-or-absolute) also possibly related: [`document.getElementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint)

Comment: Interesting, but in 2337630 the objects are limited to a set inside a div. I'm looking for something more general, because I'm looking in the whole document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following algorithm:

1. find out the x and y coordinates of mouse.
2. Use document.elementFromPoint, add returned element to array.
3. Hide that element using display:none
4. Go to 2 until returned element is document.body
5. Display all hidden elements.

Comment: I had no idea such a method existed.  Nice!