# How to find element by offset using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery find element at a particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position)

I have coordinates of some position, and I need to find nearest element matching given selector that occupies this position. Preferably with jQuery.

For example, find out deepest div element on this page that occupies space that includes point x=10, y=20.

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942776/jquery-find-element-at-a-particular-position

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337630/find-html-element-nearest-to-position-relative-or-absolute

Comment: Thanks guys! My google skills failed. (Voted to close)