# Find closest element to click and style it with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, click, compare, coordinates

I have a loop that generates 200 links and places them randomly on the page. I'm trying to make the closest link change color on a document click event. So If I click white space, the closet link to the click will change color. How can I achieve this given the following code that generates the links:

```
var links = "<a  class='links'" ;

for (var i=0; i<200; i++)
{
var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*1001)+1);
document.write(links+"href='#'"+"style="+'"'+"left:"+randomnumber+'px;"'+"id="+i+">links</a><br>");
}
```

Any broad ideas on how to do this conceptually will be appreciated, in addition to specific code examples. I've explored capturing the clientX and clientY coordinates on click, but then how would I compare in a clear and logical way to the coordinates of all the links and determine the closest one from the click?

*I am not limited to using a loop to generate the links, but I'd like to keep things concise as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you publish the page address, so I won't hit at it by accident ;).

Comment: Though the page sounds horrible, the question itself is interesting. Also it has been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337630/find-html-element-nearest-to-position-relative-or-absolute)...

Comment: check my answer it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Look [at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/54M7s/6/) :)

I'm sorry haven't seen the previous answer when i go to jsfiddle also i'm sorry if 
it's a bad answer.

```
 $("div").on('click', function(e) {
       var clkTop = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
         $("a").each(function() {
               var aTop  = $(this).position().top,
               aLeft = $(this).position().left;

               var d = Math.sqrt((
                  Math.pow(
                      (e.pageX - aLeft), 2) +
                  Math.pow(
                       (e.pageY - aTop), 2) 
               ));

               if (d <= 70 && d >= -70) {
                  $("#putlinktext").text($(this).text());
                   if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
                          $(this).css('color', 'rgb(0, 255, 255)')
                   } else {
                          $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
                   }
               }
         });
      });
```

Again i'm sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the sample code at fiddle. Using jquery here and its just a barebone. Improve it as per your needs. Please check it..

http://jsfiddle.net/ah7ra/2/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/ah7ra/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var links = "<span style='display: block; cursor: pointer;' class='linkcont'><a  class='links'" ;

for (var i=0; i<200; i++)
{
var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*1001)+1);
$('#cont').append(links+"href='#'"+"style="+'"'+"left:"+randomnumber+'px;"'+"id="+i+">links</a></span>");
}

    $('.linkcont').on('click', function() {
        var a = $(this).find('a');
        var id = a.attr('id');
        a.css('color', '#f00');
        alert(id);
    }) ;

});
```

Comment: I'd recall `document.write()` is no longer working at jsFiddle, you'll need to modernize your code.

Comment: @Teemu It was working fine when i run the script at fiddle. Any ways i have edited it :-)

Comment: I suppose this works because `span`s have `display: block;` set. Links are covering the whole page, there's no other elements to click : (.

Comment: While this works because the links are aligned left, and which ever div you click will contain the link. It, however, doesn't select the closest link to the click point, only that of which div was clicked.